# Cannot edit host file even with "run as admin"

Tags: windows-8, hosts

I am trying to edit my hosts file and I cannot seem to save it. I open notepad (run as admin) and when I go to save it gives me the error: "please make sure the file isn't opened in another location." I then took a look at the processes and it's not running this file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Workaround: copy and paste host file to some other location say desktop and do edit and then replace the original file with the edited one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the file is `open`. Boot into safe mode and try to edit it. In the worst case get a Linux Live USB, boot it and edit your file from it.

Comment: Where is it open, I show no process using this file?

Comment: It doesn't have to be open by a process to be locked. The error information is inaccurate and displays that as an error.

Comment: True... well I found out where it was open, my antivirus system.